# Using a parameter to specify which sound file in Resources to play

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I've got about 20 small sound effect files in my Resources section... I would like to have a method that plays a particular sound file based on a parameter I pass it...  assuming that my sound files are named  sound01.wav, sound02.wav, etc.

```
public static void PlayMySound(string soundFile)
{
   SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.XXX);
   snd.Play()
}

PlayMySound(sound01);
PlayMySound(sound02);
etc.
```

In the above code, I want XXX to be the string soundFile

I am trying to avoid something like this...

```
public static void PlayMySound(string soundFile)
{
   if (soundFile == "sound01") { SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.sound01); }
   if (soundFile == "sound02") { SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.sound02); }
   if (soundFile == "sound03") { SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.sound03); }
   if (soundFile == "sound04") { SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.sound04); }
   if (soundFile == "sound05") { SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.sound05); }
   etc.etc.etc.
}
```

Comment: so what is your question ?

Comment: The question essentially revolved around the statement "I want the XXX to be the string soundFile"...  but I got it figured out...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer hit me shortly after I posted this...

```
public static void PlayMySound(Stream soundFile)
{
   SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(soundFile);
   snd.Play();
}

// Then I can just call it like this...
PlayMySound(Properties.Resources.sound01);
PlayMySound(Properties.Resources.sound02);
```